# Shell Script unable to execute passed command as input

Tags: shell

I am trying to execute command from script but unable to execute it.

script :command.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$1  
b=$2
echo "a=$a"
echo "b=$b"
`$a | $b`
```

**Execution command :**

bash-3.2$ ./command.sh "tar cvf - DIR" "compress -c >/export/home/tceng/Desktop/temp/TestExtractUtility/tem/DIR.tar.Z"

**ouptut :**

./command.sh "tar cvf - DIR" "compress -c >/export/home/tceng/Desktop/temp/TestExtractUtility/tem/DIR.tar.Z"

a=tar cvf - DIR

b=compress -c >/export/home/tceng/Desktop/temp/TestExtractUtility/tem/DIR.tar.Z

> /export/home/tceng/Desktop/temp/TestExtractUtility/tem/DIR.tar.Z: already has .Z suffix -- no change
>   tar: DIR: No such file or directory
>   bash-3.2$

{Note: Requirement is to pass two command completely do not modify or put logic in script}.

command directly works from prompt .
I think there is issue with > operator

Can you please suggest something on this .

Thanks,
Anil

Comment: Have you tried **eval $a | eval $b**?

Comment: Its not working :-(   I think problem is with > operator in input

Comment: @AnilBhendarkar I'm confused. What exactly do you want the script to do?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the backticks.  This seems to work for me. Is this what you wanted?

```
#!/bin/sh
a=$1  
b=$2
echo "a=$a"
echo "b=$b"
$a | $b
```